# overloading operators, what is the purpose of the overladed operator in this example

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, overloading

I have been trying to understand the use of the overloaded operator in this code, however, I cannot wrap my mind around it. I do not understand exactly the purpose of the overloaded operator or why it is needed. I know that this is a newbie question but if someone could explain it I would greatly appreciate it.

```
const int Card::operator+(const Card& B)
{
if ((faceValue ==1 || B.faceValue == 1) && (faceValue + B.faceValue)<= 11)
    return 10 + faceValue + (B.faceValue);
else
    return faceValue + (B.faceValue);

}
```

Again I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "purpose" is to add two `Card` objects together. Typically, you can only use `+` to add integer types, pointer types [with an integer type] and float types in C and C++. Anything else will need a special operator.

The actual math inside it appears to be some part of BlackJack, where an `ACE` is counted as either `1` or `10` depending on circumstances.

Edit: I personally don't think this is good use of the `operator+`, since the expectation of `operator+` is to add two things together, not apply logic and then do different additions based on some "rules of a game". This follows the rule of "no suprises". A function with a sensible name such as `CalculateHand` should be used instead.

Edit2: Further to the above "thinking", I would add that the logic of, say, a card-game should not be dealt with in the `Card`. The logic of the game belongs in whatever "handles" the cards - cards should behave exactly the same no matter what the game is, Poker, BlackJack or Solitaire.

Comment: I would agree with you 100 percent, that is partially the reason that I am asking this question. I thought the same that you did, that you would put the logic into another class all together. However, this is a class assignment and I am just trying to understand why the use of the overloaded operator and how I could use it in the future. This code was assigned by the instructor, I had nothing to do with it. Unfortunately...

Comment: I still feel stupid when it comes to this. For instance, I do not know how the overloaded operator handles the `const Card&b`. I should have this down by now, sorry to keep asking the same questions.

Comment: Right, so an overloaded `operator+`, in general, allows types that don't "naturally" add together, such as a playing card (which has a card value and a suit, so it's not just a basic number) to be added together. Another example would be if you have a "fraction" class, which has a 1/3 represented as 1 and 3, and you want to add 1/6 to make 1/2, an `Fraction operator+(const Fraction& a, const Fraction& b)` would make a lot of sense.

Comment: The use of `const Type &` as the input allows for the value to be passed as a reference, but also to be something that isn't necessarily a reference, so you could for example use `a+b+c`, which becomes `(a+b)+c`, in this case. Of course, `a+b` isn't "one variable", so you can't use it as a true reference. Passing by reference, of types that are "large" is of benefit because it takes less time and uses less space on the stack than to copy the entire class every time.

Comment: @matspetersson I am beginning to understand, thank you for taking the time to explain it. So, just to be sure, you would use an overloaded operator to add, subtract, equal etc on a class object that may or may not have on or more internal parts included in the object that you would not normally be able to do, while at the same time returning a object of class type. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, although the return type doesn't have to be a class type - `operator==` typically return `bool` (as does all the other comparison operators).

Answer (score 3):

It is IMHO a good example of when you should *not* use operator overloading. It seems the code returns a value calculated according to the rules of a specific game. Maybe BlackJack, but it doesn't matter. I think in this case it should better be a function with an appropriate name instead of an overloaded operator + as the latter has no general concept with cards.

Comment: I slightly disagree. I do agree that operator overloading should not bring surprising purposes of operators. However, I have seen that for some specific libraries (I am intentionally using library here) operators that have a little bit different meaning do make sense, if and only if they explain the behaviour of operator well. Say, for an esoteric Blackjack library (let's name it libbjack) or namespace (bjack::), overloading + with this implementation and explaining it well does not sound like an evil thing for me.

Comment: @Equalitiesofpolynomials Even then it doesn't make much sense as BlackJack allows you to have more than two cards (according to what I've just read on Wikipedia, never played that game). `Card a, b, c;` doesn't allow `a+b+c` and if you add an overload with `int+Card`, things get even worse as the potential for errors increases. But OK, if you put it in a namespace `BlackJack` (which was not part of OPs question), you might get away with it :)

Comment: @DanielFrey so yes that's the part I agree with you. :) But I thought OP is asking a general question, I did not realize that OP was asking directly for this code segment. Thus, I commented for "general operator overloading" not for this task (I shall admit I do not know how to play BlackJack)

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading comes into picture whenever you are operating on user defined types for eg: here objects of class Card. '+' operator is meant to be used for primitive data types like int, float, double. So what you are doing here is adding to the functionality of '+' to operate upon class objects.

Also @Mats Petersson mentioned is correct, you should not impose any logic in operator overloaded function, instead use different function if required.