# How to gracefully copy two dissimilar structures in C++?

Tags: c++, struct

I have two dissimilar structures with some common elements.

```
    typedef struct X {
        struct X *next
        char X1[5];
    }

    typedef struct Y {
        unsigned char Y1;
        int Y2[5];
        bool Y3;
    }Y;

    typedef struct Z {
        unsigned char Z1;
        int Z2;
        X X1;
        Y Y1;
        struct Z *next;
    }Z;


    typedef struct A {
        unsigned char A1;
        char A2[20];
        X X1; 
        Y Y1;
    }


  typedef struct B {
        unsigned char B1;
        char B2[20];
        int B3;
        Z Z1; 
    }
```

I want to copy A and B but I do not want to use reinterpret_cast as it is risky and the code would be deployed on several machines. Please suggest any graceful method of copying.

P.S. I am not allowed to change the design. :(

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to copy A and B"? Do you want to copy an instance of A to an instance of B? Something else?

Comment: Yes I want to copy a filled instance of B to A.

Comment: What are you expecting that to do? They have different content types.

Comment: Why don't you just write a function that copies between two such structures? That's the most straightforward and least intrusive approach.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and Ulrich  :  Copying each individual elements one by one, is it the only approach? I just wanted to know if any better method existed for it?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the most elegant way would be to define `operator=` for `A` and `B`, like this:

```
A & operator=(const B & b) {
    this->A1 = b.B1;
    memcpy(this->A2, b.B2, 20);
    // Handle X1, Y1, B3 and Z1 somehow - depending on your needs
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
A a;
B b;
a = b;
```

Anyways, you'll need to take care of each element separately. The compiler can't possibly guess *how* you want to handle the data properties which are of different types.

You can automate the process further, for example by making a constructor for `Z` which would take instances of `X` and `Y`.

Also, remember that's it's a good practice to provide copy constructors along with the assignement operator.

Comment: Actually, you are even allowed to also include the memory of A1 in memcopy call, but I see no reason why one should do that.

Comment: adding to @MikeMB, always prefer the copy constructor method. it is more explicit. The operator overloading is usually used in specific to object, whereas copy constructor serves your purpose.

look at daniel's answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505267/overloading-operators-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-overladed-operator-in-this-exa)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it element-by-element if you want to be portable.

For example you can just add a constructor to `A` with signature `A(const B& b)` and have that constructor copy the individual fields from `b` to `this`.  Then do the same for the sub-structs.

Comment: Hi @O'Brien : I was also thinking around the same lines of copying individual elements. But is there any other way than that??

Comment: No, if you want to be portable, you have to do it element-by-element.